# Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines

Tags: google-colaboratory

The Google Colab output is being truncated. I've looked through the settings and I didn't see a limitation there. What is the best option to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed it by writing the output on a file on drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/")
with open('/content/drive/output.txt','w') as out:
   out.write(' abcd \n')
```

Comment: What is the `chdir` for?

Comment: changes the current working directory. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm

Comment: in the end I approached the problem a different way, and I no longer need to test this. I'll upvote this, and if anyone else has the same problem and has time to test your solution,I'll mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue currently, I found this [link](https://medium.com/@prajwal.prashanth22/google-colab-drive-as-persistent-storage-for-long-training-runs-cb82bc1d5b71#:%7E:text=Google%20Colab%20provides%20a%20maximum,when%20there%20is%20heavy%20load.) on medium, check the part "How do I use Colab for long training times/runs?"

So basically according to this article you need to store checkpoints on your drive and by using callbacks from Keras, you will be able to run it nonstop.

```
from keras.callbacks import *
filepath = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/MyCNN/epochs:{epoch:03d}-val_acc:{val_acc:.3f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
```

Other solution to solve this problem is according to my researches, you should put this code to your console but make sure that you save your progress to drive, because it will be terminated in 12 hours.

```
function ClickConnect() {
console.log("Working"); 
document
  .querySelector('#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#connect')
  .click() 
}
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```