# How to preserve in streaming output in Google Colab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am training a deep learning model in Google Colab and want to get complete logs directly from the cell outputs. But Colab has truncated the streaming outputs generated in the training process, keeping only last 5000 lines. Is there a way to preserve all the outputs from Google Colab?

[image]

Comment: You can find a similar answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721458/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721458/streaming-output-truncated-to-the-last-5000-lines)